# Including apps on the PerApp VPN section on iPadOS

Tags: ipad, vpn, ipados

My company iPad supports per app VPN. So far only the VMWare Browser and Tableau (both installed from our company's App Catalog) are taking advantage of this.  There are a couple of apps I would like to use that require VPN. Is there a way I can add any app to this list?